# getContext("2d") is not a function

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me, why getContext("2d") is not a function?

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
console.log(ctx); // CanvasRenderingContext2D { ... }
```

This is my Error:
Uncaught TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function

Comment: Try `var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];` It's getElement*s*, so it returns an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using getElementsByTagName , it will return an array with all elements with tag "canvas" and getContext('2d') wont work on an array

either select using id or choose first item in the array

```js
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
console.log(ctx); // CanvasRenderingContext2D { ... }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

**getElementsByTagName** return an array of elements. so you can reference the first one or change the method to **getElementById** which returns an element (in this case don't forget to add id to the wanted canvas).

```
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[o];
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
```